# CollectionView with Horizontal Layout ScrollTo Method not working Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a `CollectionView` to show a list of elements in `Xamarin.Forms`. I have also set `CollectionView.ItemsLayout` property to `GridItemsLayout`. But when I use `ScrollTo` method to scroll the element it does not scroll to the said element. How can I scroll to a specified index or specified element in `CollectionView`?

Code:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="fyCarousel" HeightRequest="30" Margin="0,10,10,0"  
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
       <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalItemSpacing="10">
            </GridItemsLayout>
       </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
</CollectionView>
```

For Scrolling I am using:

```
int pos = chipsSections.IndexOf(x => x.Name == Name);
fyCarousel.ScrollTo(pos);
```

Comment: On which event are you trying to set this?

Comment: Did any breakpoint hit at your second part of code?

Comment: @FreakyAli I tried this when one of the items in DataTemplate is clicked.

Comment: @Shaw Yes it did.